# How to link docker containers on build?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I linked my app container to postgres on `run`:

```
docker run --link postgres:postgres someproject/develop
```

and it worked fine.

But I realized that I need to install some stuff to database with django command before `run`. So I need linking while `build`.

How can I do that?

`docker build -h` doesn't have `--link` option.

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? You want to run a script on your database?

Comment: @behe kind of. I need to run two django management commands that will prepare database for application. But in simple term — yes, I need to run some script for my database.

Comment: It is possible to start your database and fill it while building your image. It is not possible to link containers on build. (Might this be a: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @behe how? I don't want to have DB in the app container (what I have right now)
PS I know what XYProblem is, and I asked about feature that I need.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the answer from the docker contributor Brian Goff:

```
docker run -d --name mydb postgres
docker run --rm --link mydb:db myrailsapp rake db:migrate
docker run -d --name myapp --link mydb:db myrailsapp
```

This is going to fire up postgres.
Fire up a container which does the db migration and immediately exits and removes itself.
Fires up the rails app.

Think of the build process like compiling an application. You don't seed data into a database as part of the compilation phase.

Answer (score 11):

True, but `docker build` does accept the `--network` option.

You can put your prerequisite containers on a named / custom network, e.g.:

```
docker network create whatever
docker run --network whatever --name postgres [etc.] someproject/develop
```

Then build on that network:

```
docker build --network whatever [etc.]
```

Works well.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this.  You could either build a child image of postgres, or update the database every time you start the container.

Comment: @syabro Did you check the ONBUILD command? Check this http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to speed up image builds with the help of `apt-cacher`. It runs in its own container and somehow other images, which I built, had to communicate with it.

The solution was to publish `apt-cacher` port on all interfaces. This includes e.g. `docker0`, which is available to intermediate containers spawned during image build.

Example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:8

RUN ping -c 2 172.17.0.1
```

And this is how it builds:

```
$ docker build - <dock
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:8
 ---> 47af6ca8a14a
Step 2 : RUN ping -c 2 172.17.0.1
 ---> Running in 4f56ce7c7b63
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
--- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.117/0.123/0.130/0.000 ms
 ---> 5c73a36a0a6a
Removing intermediate container 4f56ce7c7b63
```

Comment: have you tried to use compose?
How do you discovered that ip: 172.17.0.1?

Comment: 172.17.0.1 is the default address allocated for `docker0` interface (you can configure it by passing `--bip` to `docker daemon`. By default, compose will attempt to connect all service containers to a private network. There is again a bridge and it has a different address.