# Cannot connect to mysql in docker container "php" on build step

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I tried create docker image to deploy my application, i choose mysql, php, nginx as my develop enviroment. Is my `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./
    container_name: php
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1111
      MYSQL_DATABASE: magento
      MYSQL_USER: manager
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1111
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    links:
      - mysql
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl \
wget \
git \
vim \
libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libxslt-dev \
libicu-dev \
libmcrypt-dev \
libpng-dev \
libxml2-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
gd \
intl \
soap \
xsl \
zip \
pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install- 
dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer config -g http-basic.repo.magento.com -a 
5310458a34d580de1700dfe826ff19a1 255059b03eb9d30604d5ef52fca7465d
RUN composer create-project --repository- 
url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .

RUN php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url="http://localhost/" \
--db-host="mysql" \
--db-name="magento" \
--db-user="manager" \
--db-password="1111" \
--backend-frontname="admin" \
--admin-firstname="admin" \
--admin-lastname="admin" \
--admin-email="admin@admin.com" \
--admin-user="admin" \
--admin-password="admin123" \
--language="en_US" \
--currency="USD" \
--timezone="America/New_York" \
--use-rewrites="1"
```

After i run docker-compose up --build, it make error on step `RUN php bin/magento setup:install...`

```
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

In InstallCommand.php line 264:

Parameter validation failed
```

I know that error connection to db and if i remove this step and run his inside php container, all will be fine. Please help me, how can i connect to my database on build step?

Comment: try to create links to mysql for `php` container like for `adminer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link docker containers on build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551279/how-to-link-docker-containers-on-build)

Comment: Build time isn't the right time to do database setup.  The image you built should still work even if you delete and recreate the database container, or run the same image on a different host.

Comment: @Bless i am using docker-compose, your example is just docker

Comment: @BukharovSergey it doesn't work

Comment: @DavidMaze when i need setup my db, if i wanna deploy my enviroments by 1 comman?